# WebView não aparece a pagina

Tags: android, android-webview

Configurei meu `WebView` para exibir a politica de privacidade da minha aplicação, porém na hora de abrir ele aparece que a página da web não está disponível. Vejam:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_content);
    webView.loadUrl("https://paivadeveloperpolitica.wordpress.com/2017/03/28/politica-de-privacidade/");
}
```

Já tentei de varias formas, tirando o HTTOS, deixando somente HTTP, só www. , porém de nenhuma forma funcionou.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/white">

  <WebView
      android:id="@+id/wv_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Concedeu permissão de acesso a internet no AndroidManifest?

Comment: Era isso mesmo , sou muito burro kk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma como está fazendo está correta, porém você precisa conceder permissão de acesso a internet no seu `AndroidManifest.xml` para que a página seja aberta através do seu `WebView`. Veja abaixo:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: @paiva normal... também já apanhei muito.

Comment: Kkkkk tá difícil